# Sybase Merge is not allowed because different merge actions are referenced in the same WHEN [NOT] MATCHED clause

Tags: database, merge, sybase

I am trying to make a merge between table1 and table2, and I am sure that the table2 is returning unique elements, but I am getting the below error in Sybase.

**Msg451, Merge is not allowed because different merge actions are referenced in the same WHEN [NOT] MATCHED clause.**

Merge Into table1 as G using (tableB) as D
on G.id = D.id
When MATCHED then
   updated set ...
when not MATCHED then 
   insert ...

Answer (score 0):

The current ASE implementation of MERGE indeed has some limitations, as the error message says. Unfortunately these do not seem to be documented.

Comment: Yes I tried to look for any documentation or explanation, but is not easy to determine what is the cause of the problem from the message, if you have any idea or advice it will be most welcome :), thanks for your comment.